# matlab: how to speed up the count of consecutive values in a cell array

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, cell

I have the 137x19 cell array Location(1,4).loc and I want to find the number of times that horizontal consecutive values are present in Location(1,4).loc. I have used this code:

```
x=Location(1,4).loc;
y={x(:,1),x(:,2)};
for ii=1:137
cnt(ii,1)=sum(strcmp(x(:,1),y{1,1}{ii,1})&strcmp(x(:,2),y{1,2}{ii,1}));
end
y={x(:,1),x(:,2),x(:,3)};
for ii=1:137
cnt(ii,2)=sum(strcmp(x(:,1),y{1,1}{ii,1})&strcmp(x(:,2),y{1,2}{ii,1})&strcmp(x(:,3),y{1,3}{ii,1}));
end
y={x(:,1),x(:,2),x(:,3),x(:,4)};
for ii=1:137
cnt(ii,3)=sum(strcmp(x(:,1),y{1,1}{ii,1})&strcmp(x(:,2),y{1,2}{ii,1})&strcmp(x(:,3),y{1,3}{ii,1})&strcmp(x(:,4),y{1,4}{ii,1}));
end
 y={x(:,1),x(:,2),x(:,3),x(:,4),x(:,5)};
for ii=1:137
cnt(ii,4)=sum(strcmp(x(:,1),y{1,1}{ii,1})&strcmp(x(:,2),y{1,2}{ii,1})&strcmp(x(:,3),y{1,3}{ii,1})&strcmp(x(:,4),y{1,4}{ii,1})&strcmp(x(:,5),y{1,5}{ii,1}));
end
```

... continue for all the columns. This code run and gives me the correct result but it's not automated and it's slow. Can you give me ideas to automate and speed up the code?

Comment: If they are numbers, why not convert it to a matrix first? Use number equality instead of string compare?

Comment: yes, good idea! So, I haven't to rexrite every time y= .... can you suggest a metod to speed up the code avoid to riwrite sum(strcmp ....) for 18 times?

Comment: also consider `diff`

Comment: now that I read the code more carefully, it is not doing what you described (counting horizontal consecutive values)! You should post a small example of an input matrix and the expected output.. The question is not clear as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I will write an answer to this since I've not done so for a while.
First convert your cell Array to a matrix,this will ease the following steps by a lot. Then `diff` is the way to go

```
A = randi(5,[137,19]);
DiffA = diff(A')'; %// Diff creates a matrix that is 136 by 19, where each consecutive value is subtracted by its previous value.
```

So a 0 in DiffA would represent 2 consecutive numbers in A are equal, 2 consecutive 0s would mean 3 consecutive numbers in A are equal.

```
idx = DiffA==0;
cnt(:,1) = sum(idx,2);
```

To do 3 consecutive number counts, you could do something like:

```
idx2 = abs(DiffA(:,1:end-1))+abs(DiffA(:,2:end)) == 0; 
cnt(:,2) = sum(idx2,2);
```

Or use another Diff, the abs is used to avoid negative number + positive number that also happens to give 0; otherwise only 0 + 0 will give you a 0; you can now continue this pattern by doing:

```
idx3 = abs(DiffA(:,1:end-2))+abs(DiffA(:,2:end-1))+abs(DiffA(:,3:end)) == 0
cnt(:,3) = sum(idx3,2);
```

In loop format:

```
absDiffA = abs(DiffA)
for ii = 1:W
   absDiffA = abs(absDiffA(:,1:end-1) + absDiffA(:,1+1:end));
   idx = (absDiffA == 0);
   cnt(:,ii) = sum(idx,2);
end
```

NOTE: this method counts [0,0,0] twice when evaluating 2 consecutives, and once when evaluating 3 consecutives.